# Permit side effect of a function

Tags: reference, ocaml, record, mutable

I have defined a module `Comp` whose operations are quite costly. In most of the cases, for a value of type `Comp.t`, a value of type `int` can be calculated, which can be used to accelarate many operations. So I define a type `x` as follows which represents 2 cases: 1) the integer has been calculated 2) otherwise

```
type x = A of (Comp.t, int) | B of Comp.t
```

A function `convert: x -> x` has been written to try to calculate the integer for a `Comp.t`, it is possible that this integer does not exist, this function is costly as well:

```
let convert (v: x): x =
  match v with
  | A _ -> v
  | B c -> 
    try to calculate the integer "i" from "c", 
    return "A (c, i)" if the integer is found; otherwise, return "B c".
```

Initially, a comparaison function `less than` can be written like this:

```
open Comp

let lt (x0: x) (x1: x): bool =
  let x0, x1 = Comp.convert x0, Comp.convert x1 in
  match x0, x1 with
    | A (c0, i0), A (c1, i1) -> 
      i0 < i1 (* which is very fast *)
    | A (c0, _), B c1 | B c0, A (c1, _) | B c0, B c1 -> 
      Comp.lt c0 c1 (* which is quite slow *)

...
let b0 = lt x0_o x1_o in
let b1 = le x0_o x1_o in (* "le" call "convert" too *) 
let b2 = ge x0_o x1_o in (* "ge" call "convert" too *)
...
```

As `convert` is costly, and there are many other functions than `lt` which may call it from time to time (e.g. `le`, `ge`), I would like to make the conversion impact the value outside. For instance, I want the `lt` to change the value of `x0_o` and `x1_o`, so that the functions later (e.g. `le`, `ge`) receive arguments which probably have already been converted, that results in a faster computation for the whole block.

So I guess something like mutable record should be used, could anyone give me an example? Also, in general, is it a good idea to do this (permitting side effects) to optimise the computation?

Comment: why would "the integer not be found"?

Comment: the integer is something I define myself... In some cases, I consider it does not make sense to have an integer... Well, it is true that a special value can be associated in these cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is memoize (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the function Comp.convert (if it's pure):

This memoization code uses a hashtable to store the results instead of recalculating them (replaced the function Comp.convert with a very simple one to test the code):

```
let convert x = x +  3

let convert_m' () = 
  let tbl = Hashtbl.create 100 in
  (fun x -> if Hashtbl.mem tbl x then Hashtbl.find tbl x else 
      begin 
        let n = convert x in
        Hashtbl.add tbl x n;
        n 
      end
  )

let convert_m = convert_m' ()
let b = convert_m 6
```

Comment: Thank you... The structure of `Comp.t` is complicated, so I am afraid the complexity of `Hashtbl.mem` and `Hashtbl.find` is high?

Comment: It doesn't matter, Hashtbl is generic, you can use "complex" structures with it.